# Accounting for search terms that may include a space, using SearchWP

Tags: plugins, search

As the title suggest I am having an issue with setting up the plugin SearchWP to correctly work with search terms (product names) that may, or may not, contain spaces. e.g. "ABC1" or "ABC 1".

I am not entirely 100% sure how to approach this issue.

Like terms are not appropriate as it only deals with single words. "ABC 1" would be considered 2 separate words.

Fuzzy logic doesn't appear to achieve the correct results e.g. returning results for "ABC 2" "ABC 3" ABC 4".

I have tried the approach of a custom field of search synonyms for each product. Again that hasn't had the desired results either.

Any advice or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: SearchWP uses its own search engine, so any questsions about how it works should be directed to the plugin author/support community. It doesn't really have anything to do with WordPress development.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Apologies, I had a feeling that might be an issue. Unfortunately they appear to have closed their support forum and there isn't any presence on wordpress.org. StackExchange was my next bet.

Comment: Sorry, I can contact the plugin author. Cheers 

Comment: SearchWP uses a ticket system now for their support, send an email to support@searchwp.com, make sure to include your license key

Comment: @RiddleMeThis have done now, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate that this is in the wrong forum, but just incase this may be of some use to someone.

By using the following I can modify the search query, so that it matches the product titles. E.G if its "ABC 1" it will search for "ABC1"

```
function my_parse_searchwp_terms( $query, $engine ) {
   $query = preg_replace( '/(?<=abc)(\s+)(?=\d)/i', '', $query)
   return $query;
}

add_filter( 'searchwp_terms', 'my_parse_searchwp_terms', 10, 2 );
```